# MODX3 Manager language setting

Tags: content-management-system, modx, modx-evolution

I have a minor but annoying challenge.

When I log in to MODX3 Manager, it chooses the Finnish language based on my browser setting. That would be otherwise ok, but not everything is translated to Finnish and untranslated entries appear in Russian. So, I need to manually select English.

But I have not found a way to save the language setting. Every time I log in, the Manager sticks back to Finnish(-Russian) and I have to select English again. How could I force the Manager to keep English on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced same problem with language saving some time ago, I was going to leave issue at https://github.com/modxcms/revolution/issues but noticed such one already created. I do not see issue number right now but I know developers have been warned about this problem. Hopwfully next 3.0.4 release will cover that.

Comment: I found the issue: https://github.com/modxcms/revolution/issues/16072. It does not look like there is a solution coming. I even tried to add the manager_language setting myself but it didn't help.